# Maven build failure unable to generate war file

Tags: jenkins, maven-dependency

[enter image description here][1]Hi Team, I'm getting error while trying to build war file maven failure in jenkins can anyone help me how can I resolve the issue

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2esu.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2esu.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYats.jpg)

Comment: You tooka really bad picture (or maybe 2) of your screen, not even a screencap but an actual photo of a screen, a screen with TEXT in it and posted the picture as a poorly formed link. Why not just [copy and paste](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) (select, ctrl-c ctrl-v), and markdown format the TEXT in the message? I don't think you can be [helped](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Not even gonna try squint at the image.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.